# Metadata Manipulation Libraries for Python 3.6 Mac OS X El Capitan other than py3exiv2 & GExiv2

Tags: python, macos, metadata, exif, iptc

*I edited the question for being too opinion based.*

I am desperately searching for a library to manipulate (read/write) image metadata with Python 3.6 on Mac OS X El Capitan. I tried *GExiv2*. After approximately two hours I was able to install it and get it running, but it keeps generating further errors within Python3 I can't solve. I was not at all able to install *py3exiv2*. I could'nt find further alternatives (for Python3) to the two libraries mentioned.

Problems with *GExiv2*:

I first import the modules:

```
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('GExiv2', '0.10.04')
>>> from gi.repository.GExiv2 import Metadata
```

Then I produce a Metadata-object and open the image:

```
>>> m =  Metadata()
>>> m.open_path('Abb_WS_di-34_561_01.jpg')
True
```

When, however, I try to use the Metadata-Objects methods like `m.get_tags()`. I get an Error:

```
>>> m.get_tags()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Metadata' object has no attribute 'get_tags'
```

`.get_tags()` sums up the "lower" `get_XYZ_tags()`methods and returns the concatenated lists produced by these methods. Calling a "lower" method like `m.get_iptc_tags()` works:

```
>>> m.get_iptc_tags()
['Iptc.Application2.Byline', 'Iptc.Application2.City',     'Iptc.Application2.CountryCode', … ]

>>> m.get_tag_string('Iptc.Application2.CountryName')
'Deutschland'
```

I looked in the module and made sure that the methods are there. Maybe someone can give me a clue …

Thanks in advance!

Comment: HI! Welcom to SO. PLease note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Could recreate the example from https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775249#c0 ? Does it work? I have my doubts about using empty initialization of ``Metadata()``.

Comment: @mcepl: @mcepl The empty `Metadata()`is a work around for another error (maybe this work around does not function really well): 

    >>> exif = GExiv2.Metadata('IMG_1234.JPG')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

The discussion in the link you've provided did not help me solve my problem mentioned above.